# extract text from specific sections in html, python

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.7

I'm trying to do a program that show uou lyrics of a song, but i get stuck on this error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

here's the code:

```py
def get_lyrics(url):
    lyrics_html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(lyrics_html.content, "html.parser")
    lyrics = soup.find('div', {"class": "lyrics"})
    return lyrics.text
```

This is the [site](https://genius.com) where i take the lyrics.
I can't explain whats wrong, for example i'll search the lyrics of [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIPyw84l27c), so here's the lyrics of the song: [click](https://genius.com/Luis-sal-ciao-mi-chiamo-luis-lyrics).
You can see from yourself that in the page the "place" where the lyrics is, a div with class "lyrics". This is how all lyrics pages of this site are made. Can someone help me pls? Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page returns two versions of page (probably to confuse **scrapers** and bots). One version with class that begins on `"Lyrics__Container..."` and one with class `lyrics`. If a tag with class `Lyrics__Container` is not found, the lyrics are inside the tag with class `lyrics`.

This should always print a lyrics:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://genius.com/Luis-sal-ciao-mi-chiamo-luis-lyrics'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

text = soup.select_one('div[class^="Lyrics__Container"], .lyrics').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
[Intro]
Ah, mhh (ehi)
Ho la bocca piena
Va bene
[Verse]
Ciao, mi chiamo Luis (eh, eh-eh)
Ciao, mi chiamo Luis (eh, eh-eh)
Ciao, Ciao mi chiamo Luis (eh, eh-eh)
Ciao, mi chiamo Luis
Si, si, si Sal
A a a a Si si si si si si
Proprio così mi chiamo io
Ciao mi chiamo Luis Aah

... and so on.
```

---

EDIT: Updated version:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://genius.com/Avicii-the-nights-lyrics'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')

def get_text(elements):
    text = ''
    for c in elements:
        for t in c.select('a, span'):
            t.unwrap()
        if c:
            c.smooth()
            text += c.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')
    return text


cs = soup.select('div[class^="Lyrics__Container"]')
if cs:
    text = get_text(cs)
else:
    text = get_text(soup.select('.lyrics'))

print(text)
```

Prints:

```
[Verse 1]
(Hey)
Once upon a younger year
When all our shadows disappeared
The animals inside came out to play (Hey)
Hey, went face to face with all our fears
Learned our lessons through the tears
Made memories we knew would never fade
[Pre-Chorus]
One day my father he told me
Son, don't let it slip away

...etc.
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer and for explainin, one last thing, in some song there are some things like [this](https://imgur.com/a/qEmQPc1), that doesn't make any sense and the lyrics format is like [here](https://imgur.com/a/hDGkDET) there isn't a way for remove that class, saving the text?

Comment: [here you are](https://genius.com/Avicii-the-nights-lyrics)

Comment: i tired, it gives me the following: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`, referred to `c.smooth()`

Comment: No, i copied the code in the right way, the link is the same you used.

Comment: I took a screenshot of the code with the error
[here](https://ibb.co/TY4CShJ)

Comment: @aleee That's strange. I updated my answer. But try to `print(soup)` and see if required tags are there - maybe you get some error page or captcha.

Comment: i printed it, there isn't the tag <a span> but there is a class so i tried replacing `for t in c.select('a, span')` in `for t in c.select('a[class^="referent referent--yellow"]')` but is not working giving the same error

Comment: the tags seems change every time i run the code how is it possbile!?

Comment: @aleee `c.select('a, span')` means to select `<a>` tag **or** `<span>` tag. These tags I try to remove before getting the text. Yes, the site is changing the tags every time - it's the form of protection from the scrappers (i think). You need to adapt the code to every version of page, or try to run the script again if it produces error (and it will hopefully get the right version this time).

Comment: Gotcha, mh, what if instead remove a specific tag, we don't remove all the tags that aren't text?

Comment: @aleee To not clutter this comment section, I recommend to open a new question here on Stack Overflow and put there code you have and describe the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this link https://genius.com/Luis-sal-ciao-mi-chiamo-luis-lyrics
instead of https://genius.com/ which you have mentioned as song.

```
def get_lyrics(url):
    lyrics_html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(lyrics_html.text, "lxml")
    lyrics_text = []
    lyrics = soup.find_all('div', class_="Lyrics__Container-sc-1ynbvzw-2 jgQsqn")
    for i in lyrics:
        lyrics_text.append(i.text.strip())
        # print(i.text.strip())
    return lyrics_text

output = get_lyrics("https://genius.com/Luis-sal-ciao-mi-chiamo-luis-lyrics")
```

Output will be:

```
['[Intro]Ah, mhh (ehi)Ho la bocca pienaVa bene[Verse]Ciao, mi chiamo Luis (eh, eh-eh)Ciao, mi chiamo Luis (eh, eh-eh)Ciao, Ciao mi chiamo Luis (eh, eh-eh)Ciao, mi chiamo LuisSi, si, si SalA a a a Si si si si si siProprio così mi chiamo ioCiao mi chiamo Luis AahLuis Sal, Luis, Luis, Luis SalCiao mi chiamo Luis, Luis SalEeemEeeCiao, Ciao BolognaMi chiamo LuisCiao Mamma (Eee) EeeCiao, Ciao anche a voi LuistiMi chiamo Luis, Lo youtuber EeeEeeCiao, Sono uno youtuberMi chiamo LuisSono uno youtuberEeeCiao, Sono uno youtuberMi chiamo LuisSono uno youtuberA e (Diglielo Luis) a e ă a e e a ă a a a-aaaaCiao mi chiamo LuisEee (Ma chi ti caga)Eee Ciao (Ma chi vuoi che ti guardi)Mi chiamo LuisHahahahaEeeVoglio diventare uno youtuberEee', '', '[Outro]Uuu BolognaDuemila EeeEee EeeEe']
```